# Install istio on aks using azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-aks, istio

I’m trying to install istio on aks using azure devops pipeline but not able to get yaml file and also not able to create using istioctl.

I’m able to download the istio using curl but not able to set env variable on agent host and not able to use istioctl

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share error code or current pipeline yaml, if any ?